# WSO2 emm : Not able to give application store access

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup wso2 emm 2.0.1. When I login to https://localhost:9443/store with admin credentials it works fine. I am able to install applications to users device from emm store .However login to emm store with user credentials gives me an error as insufficient previleges . Which role needs to be assigned to the user to give store access. I have tried to assign Internal/store role but not able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to carbon console.(Home   > Identity  > Users and Roles   > List  > Users     > Permissions)
Then assign permissions for Role:Subscribe permission in WebApp(Admin permission>Manage>Webapp-subscribe)

Answer (score -1):

you need to assign "Mobile App" permissions for Role: Internal/store-admin.